# How to create a translucent client area in c#/.net?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

How can I create a client area/control with translucent effect in WPF/Windows forms.Like the "aero theme" and the "picasa photo viewer"?

Config:Win7/VS2008.

thanks.

Comment: Nobody will know what you mean until you call it "glass".  http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Glass-In-C-An-Alternative-Approach.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF windows have the property `AllowsTransparency`, if that is set to true `WindowStyle` needs to be set to `None` but the window may be transparent then, you can set `Opacity` and `Background` to appropriate values if you want some sort of glass effect.

Comment: Yes, that is the downside of it, you'll need to define your own buttons for that, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you can set [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) to `None` and [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) to true, then leave transparent areas in the content.

In WinForms, you'll need to make a layered window.